# Laravel resource return empty array

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have resource where i get product data trough third table but having hard time make relationships work on models so it return empty array.

## Logic

1. Product has many barcodes
2. Barcodes can have (belongsTo) damage
3. In damage we get product trough barcode table (we store `barcode_id`)

> I also included fillable part of each column so you can see columns in database.

## Code

`Product model`

```
class Product extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'slug', 'stock', 'cover', 'description', 'sku', 'price', 'discount',
    ];

    public function barcodes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Barcode::class);
    }
}
```

`Barcode model`

```
class Barcode extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_id', 'sku', 'serial_number', 'price', 'discount',
    ];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    public function damages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DamageProduct::class);
    }
}
```

`DamageProduct model`

```
class DamageProduct extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'outlet_id', 'user_id', 'barcode_id', 'description',
    ];

    public function barcode()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Barcode::class);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

`DamageProductsResource resource`

```
class DamageProductsResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        $arrayData = [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'outlet' => new OutletsResource($this->whenLoaded('outlet')),
            'user' => new usersResource($this->whenLoaded('user')),
            'barcode' => new BarcodeResource($this->whenLoaded('barcode')),
            'description' => $this->description,
        ];

        return $arrayData;
    }
}
```

`Result`

[image: one]

**Any idea?**

## Update

In case you need to see how `BarcodeResource` resource looks like here it is:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
        $arrayNull = [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'product' => new ProductsResource($this->whenLoaded('product')),
            'sku' => $this->sku,
            'serial_number' =>  $this->serial_number ? (Int) $this->serial_number : null,
            'price' => (Int) $this->price,
            'discount' => $this->discount ? (Int) $this->discount : null,
        ];
}
```

Comment: I do not want to poke an open wound, but this is why it is so important not to do `$variable = xxx; return $variable;` and just do `return xxxx;` every time. There is no sense in following a code style like that, it is just prone to this type of issue, and you are adding 2 lines of code (new line + `return`) just because. Again, just leaving this for anyone reading this in the future. I am so against the code style you are using (just the return thing) because I have seen this issue millions of times, and this is perfect proof of why not follow that style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you simply forgot the `return` statement in your `BarcodeResource`

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    $arrayNull = [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'product' => new ProductsResource($this->whenLoaded('product')),
        'sku' => $this->sku,
        'serial_number' =>  $this->serial_number ? (Int) $this->serial_number : null,
        'price' => (Int) $this->price,
        'discount' => $this->discount ? (Int) $this->discount : null,
    ];
    return $arrayNull; // this is missing
}
```

Comment: That's absolutely right but somehow product data isn't include barcode resource! `screenshot` https://ibb.co/sPyL2bk

Comment: the issue was from controller i needed to add barcode relation in `with()` as well. Thank you.  `->with(['outlet', 'barcode', 'barcode.product', 'user'])`